# How to make a class always reconstruct on copy/move?

Tags: c++

Say I have a class `A` which holds a pointer to the class that contains it, and its size:

```
struct A
{
    void* parent;
    std::size_t size;
    template<typename T> A(T* p) : parent(p), size(sizeof(T)) { }
};
```

This is used in other classes as follows:

```
struct B
{
    A a { this };
};
```

So far, so good. But problems arise when the containing class is copied or moved. `A` is never reconstructed, and still points to the *previous* instance of `B`:

```
B b1;
B b2 = b1;
assert(b1.a.parent != b2.a.parent); // oops!
```

The obvious solution would be to delete `A`'s copy and move constructors:

```
struct A
{
    void* parent;
    std::size_t size;
    template<typename T> A(T* p) : parent(p), size(sizeof(T)) { }
    A(const A&) = delete;
    A(A&&) = delete;
};
```

... but this would force me to define custom copy/move constructors and `operator=` in any class where `A` is used. 
Is there an easier way to achieve the same effect?

edit: I should have mentioned, `A` does some 'dirty' tricks with the memory occupied by its parent class. It needs a pointer to `parent`, and must be able to figure out its size.

Comment: This does not look like a sane design decision.

Comment: Can you recommend a better design? I need a pointer to the containing class and I don't really see any other way to do it.

Comment: The real question is *why* do you need a pointer to the containing class? Composition means making a complex thing out of simpler things. Example: Does the wheel of a car need to know anything about the car?

Comment: Going with the car analogy, you could say `A` is the car's key. When creating a second, identical car, you wouldn't want the first car's keys be able to unlock the second car.

Comment: Agreed, my car analogy isn't the best. Could you provide (possibly striped down) real code, or describe what you actually want to achieve?

Comment: My goal is to make `A` "pin" the memory occupied by `B`, to prevent `B` from being paged out.

Answer (score 2):

Store the offset of `A` from the beginning of its owner.

```
struct A
{
    std::ptrdiff_t parent_offset;
    template<typename T> A(T* p) : parent_offset(
        reinterpret_cast<std::uintptr_t>(this) -
        reinterpret_cast<std::uintptr_t>(p)
      )
    {}

    void* parent() { 
       return reinterpret_cast<void*>(
                  reinterpret_cast<std::uintptr_t>(this) - parent_offset
         );
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Using inheritance and the "curiously recurring template pattern" is another way to solve this:

```
template<typename T> struct A
{
    T* const ptr;
    const std::size_t size;

    A() : ptr(this), size(sizeof(T)) { }
    A(A&&) : A() { }
    A(const A&) : A() { }
};

struct B: A<B>
{
};
```

Although I'm not sure if this is to be preferred over @n.m.'s solution.

Answer (score 0):

wrong design:

```
struct parent;

struct inner {
  void do_something() { 
    do_stuff();
    parent->do_stuff();
    more_stuff();
  }
  parent* p;
};

struct parent {
  void do_something() { inner.do_something(); }
  inner my_inner = inner { this };
}
```

right design:

```
struct inner {
  void do_stuff();
  void more_stuff();
}

struct parent {
  void do_something() {
    my_inner.do_stuff();
    do_stuff();
    my_inner.more_stuff();
  }
  inner my_inner;
};
```

Comment: This is not what I'm looking for, since my inner class does some low-level tricks with the parent pointer. It doesn't expose any methods.